# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am learning data scraping in python 3.5 and trying to find the existence of a word on website, i am getting error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

```
 pyladies_source = uReq("http://pyladies.com")
 pyladies_source = pyladies_source.read()
'python' in pyladies_source
```

Comment: It sounds like the type of `pyladies_source` is in bytes

Comment: Have you tried  `str()`?

Comment: can you tell me the code for the solution, i not that proficient in python

Comment: In the future, please provide your imports when you use custom naming for imports.  For example, show that you used `from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pyladies_source = uReq("http://pyladies.com")
pyladies_source = pyladies_source.read()
'python' in str(pyladies_source) # Returns false in this case, at least when I ran it.
```

All you had to change was casting `pyladies_source` to a string so you can look for `'python'`